# Laravel Hash::make() and Hash::check() not working with Postgres

Tags: postgresql, laravel, hash

Im having a strange issue with Laravel 5, Postgres and the Hash facade. I have the following test code:

```
public static function addNewPartner($args){
    $user = new User;
    $user->username = $args['username'];
    $user->email = $args['email'];
    // Here starts the issue
    $password = Hash::make($args['password']);
    $user->password = $password;
    $user->remote_key = str_random(16);
    if(!$user->save()){
        return false;
    }
    $role = Role::where('name','=','partner')->first();
    $user->attachRole($role);
    Log::info("User::addNewPartner. User:" . json_encode($user));

    // At this point the password is hashed and saved into DB, I can
    // see the record saved. 

    // I compare the saved password with the input and it fails. 
    if(Hash::check($args['password'], $user->password)){
        Log::info('DB hash' . " " . $password);
    } else {
        Log::info('DB no hash' . " " . $password);
    }

    // I compare the password as it was generated with the input and 
    // it passes. 
    if(Hash::check($args['password'], $password)){
        Log::info('LOCAL hash' . " " . $password);
    } else {
        Log::info('LOCAL no hash' . " " . $password);
    }


    return $user;
}
```

The log output is:

[2016-04-28 12:04:46] local.INFO: UserController::postAddnewpartner. Input:{"token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjIsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6XC9cL3Vici5sb2NhbDo4MDAwXC9hcGlcL3VzZXJcL2xvZ2luIiwiaWF0IjoxNDYxODYyNDYwLCJleHAiOjE0NjE4NjYwNjAsIm5iZiI6MTQ2MTg2MjQ2MCwianRpIjoiZmU0MTgzMTAwMzQyMjU3Mjg2MGJmOWJhN2FmOWIyMDMifQ.iUZzepZshdn7snUGOzTt3AEAyfRKNGPrCJpk5FxJtxw","fullname":"usuario1","email":"usuario1@usuario.com","password":"1234","username":"usuario1"}

[2016-04-28 12:04:46] local.INFO: User::addNewPartner. User:{"username":"usuario1","email":"usuario1@usuario.com","remote_key":"jhDpJgolw4bTdsZj","updated_at":"2016-04-28 12:04:46","created_at":"2016-04-28 12:04:46","id":6}

[2016-04-28 12:04:46] local.INFO: DB no hash $2y$10$PU24f.AkNguifnh1AkKSJuVu7I4idWGUz8SA2L/37sRsI6JaVkQZC

[2016-04-28 12:04:46] local.INFO: LOCAL hash $2y$10$PU24f.AkNguifnh1AkKSJuVu7I4idWGUz8SA2L/37sRsI6JaVkQZC

For some reason the Hash::check() doesnt work if the record is retrieved from the database.

Curiously the test users created during the seeding process work:

```
class UserTableSeeder extends Seeder {

public function run() {
    $users = array(
        array(
            'username' => 'admin',
            'email' => 'admin@example.org',
            'password' => Hash::make('1234'),
            'parent_id'=>null,
            'created_at' => new DateTime,
            'updated_at' => new DateTime,
        ),
```

My user migration is:

```
public function up() {
    Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('parent_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->string('username')->unique();
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password', 60);
        $table->string('remote_key')->default(str_random(16));
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Do you know why the Hash is failing? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was precisely on these lines:

```
$password = Hash::make($args['password']);
// more code
if(!$user->save()){
    return false;
}
```

At the moment of saving the user the password was hashed, therefore the program was hashing a hash. So, the lines:

```
// I compare the saved password with the input and it fails. 
if(Hash::check($args['password'], $user->password)){
    Log::info('DB hash' . " " . $password);
} else {
    Log::info('DB no hash' . " " . $password);
}
```

were actually comparing the hashed hash stored at the database with the hashed password, as a consequence the comparison returned false.